# What does the word "mortability" exactly mean?

Tags: expressions, medical

I've come across quite a few medical articles in which the word "mortability" appears.
e.g. In the National Library of Medicine : https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=mortability.
As I strongly doubt that this word has ever existed, I've looked up a couple of dictionaries on line and at home, only to discover that none of them accepts such an entry and, as a consequence, I haven't been able to find any definition so far. Can anyone help?

Comment: It appears to be a rare variant of mortality

Comment: Yes. It appears so. But, no dictionary accounts for it. Hence, my question.

Comment: Looks like a parallel to *morbidity*. An article (*Evaluation of the effect of HIV virus on the digestive flora of infected versus non infected infants*) has "high morbidity or high mortability," which means "a lot of sickness and a lot of death."

Answer (score 1):

It's a ["nonce-word"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/565996/what-does-the-word-mortability-exactly-mean) (a "one-off" neologism that in this case may have been coined more than once and/or occasionally copied). Here it is in the 1928 publication [Journal of State Medicine - Volume 36](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mortability%20as%20I%20should%22)

> *It is important to distinguish between liability to attack — **infectability** — and liability to die as the result of that attack - **mortability** as I should like to term it*

The word ***infectability*** is perfectly valid, but I doubt you'd find ***mortability*** in any dictionary. Clearly it's based on ***mortality***, with the specific sense of (measurable) "death rate" / "chances of dying".

---

Thanks to [@rajah9](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3306/rajah9) for pointing out that the "correct" term (as defined in [the full Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/122124?redirectedFrom=morbidity#eid)) is...

> **morbidity** 1b. Medicine
> *The **rate** of disease, or a specific disease, in a population; (emphasis mine)
>
> = **morbidity rate***

And [here's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mortability%22%20%22morbidity%22) a Google Books link showing just how often the "equivalent" terms ***mortability*** and ***morbidity*** occur in close proximity within the same text (*surprisingly* often, I would say). One almost gets the impression many medical writers would *like* the former term to have greater currency. So they keep writing it (alongside the "correct, explanatory" word "morbidity"). But dictionary-makers keep ignoring them!

Comment: "... liability to die as the result of that attack - mortability..." So, "mortability" would be a portmanteau word based on the words "mortality" and "liability". One may wonder why, after nearly 100 years, it doesn't appear in any dictionary.

Comment: Fairly obviously because ***we don't need it***. Most people would presumably understand "morbidity" to mean *The **condition or state** of being diseased* (OED definition **1a**). But I've cited their second definition, which completely matches the intended sense of the nonce-word.

Comment: If "mortability" means "liability to die as the result of that attack", as per the first quote, then that _doesn't_ match the meaning of "morbidity", which as you've said is "The rate of disease, or a specific disease, in a population" - that is, how many people have it. Just because 30% of the population have a cold, it doesn't mean that 30% of the population will die from having a cold!

Comment: @psmears: Well, I suppose that's true if you want to split hairs. Essentially this "problem" arises because strictly speaking ***morbidity*** just means *the condition or state of being **diseased*** (from OED defn #1, as per my earlier comment), but for the required sense here we'd like it to mean *"**fatally / terminally** diseased"*. But at the end of the day, it's obvious what writers *want* the nonce-word to mean (they usually "in-line define it" anyway), even if dictionary-makers aren't taking any notice! :)

Comment: I'm not sure the difference between "being ill" and "dying" is splitting hairs :)

Comment: @psmears: Perhaps that's why no-one has seen fit to upvote my answer. Everyone's agreeing with you and Patrick that I haven't "defined" the word accurately enough!